# Mean and Variance for a sum of independent weighted bernoulli random variables with different probabilities of success

Tags: distributions, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $Z_i$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with differing probabilities $P_i$.  Also suppose weights $W_i$ are positive and constant.

Can you tell me the mean and variance for the random variable $S$ which is the summation of each weighted $Z_i$ (i.e. $W_iZ_i$).  Furthermore is there a simple distribution for this random variable (similar to the Poisson Binomial distribution)?

Comment: What exactly are the weights supposed to *mean*?  In what sense are you "summing" these variables?  Are you literally forming the random variable $\sum_i w_i Z_i$ (as you write), or are you perhaps trying to form a *mixture* of their distributions, or maybe something else? And where you write that the weights are "constant" does that mean they are all equal to each other?

Answer (score 6):

I understand $Z_i$ takes value 1 with probability $P_i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Computing the **mean** of the weighted sum is simple: by linearity of the $\mathrm E$ operator,

$$
\mathrm E \sum_i W_i Z_i = \sum_i W_i \mathrm E Z_i = \sum_i W_i P_i.
$$

As for the **variance**, since the variables are independent you can just sum their variances. So:

$$
\mathrm{Var} \sum_i W_i Z_i = \sum_i W_i^2 \mathrm{Var}Z_i  = \sum_i W_i^2 P_i(1-P_i).
$$

The distribution of $\sum_i W_i Z_i$ does not have a name, to my knowledge.

Comment: To make it clearer that this answers (quite correctly!) *one possible interpretation* of the question, consider pointing out that the weighted sum of $n$ variables you are working with will not describe a distribution supported on the integers $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, which is the support of a Poisson-Binomial distribution (unless all the weights are equal to $1$).  This contrast casts some doubt on whether your interpretation, albeit a natural one, truly is the intended one.